# Ubuntu upgrading python packages installed by OS

Tags: python, ubuntu, six

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and PyCharm (the latter is irrelevant I think but...)

In my code, an import from the package `six` does not work and I tried updating (the version in usr/lib/python2.7/ is 1.5.2, while I need 1.10)

But I'm getting the response:

```
Found existing installation: six 1.5.2

    Not uninstalling six at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, owned by OS
Successfully installed six
```

Then, I checked my usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages folder and six 1.10 is installed there.

Now, my question is how to solve the referencing? Can I bypass the OS-installed version by default or upgrade it?

Comment: `pip` was very specifically designed to not mess up your distribution's Python installation.  If you want to upgrade your Ubuntu version, that's not a programming question, but Google `apt-get dist-upgrade`.
What you can do in isolated cases is find a newer version of the package you want to replace from a third-party source, and install that on top of your distro's version.  This is generally unsupported and slightly risky; but look for "apt pinning".

Comment: Thanks, I'll see what I can dig up. I wasn't sure if I should post the q here or on the Ubuntu part, however I thought there is some magic to solve the referencing from Python aswell.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem with requests lib I got this massage when I tried to upgrade or uninstall requests

```
Not uninstalling requests at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, owned by OS
```

so what I did and it help I just went to the dist-packages folder and deleted

**requests-2.2.1.egg-info file** and then I could upgrade normally with pip

```
sudo pip install --upgrade requests
```

in your case try delete  **six-*.*.*.egg-info**

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have two copies installed here. One is in OS directory ( /usr/lib). The other is probably by pip ( /usr/local/lib). You might be able to fix it by uninstall the 1.5.2 using

```
sudo apt-get uninstall ....
```

Then 1.10 in local directory will be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
# sudo pip install --upgrade pip
```

When you do the above you get the below error message,

```
Not uninstalling pip at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, owned by OS
```

but the new pip is actually installed in the /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip. At this point pip version still shows the pip installed in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages. To overcome this error do the below command

```
# hash -d pip

# type pip

pip is /usr/local/bin/pip

# pip --version

pip 18.0 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

This fixes the problem, it worked for me on Debian Jessie, Python 2.7

source:- https://blog.hartwork.org/posts/regarding-not-uninstalling-pip-at-usr-lib-python2-7-dist-packages-owned-by-os/

Answer (score -2):

`python-six 1.10` will come in *xenial*. Nevertheless, you don't have to upgrade your OS, you can download and install a single package.

http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/all/python-six/download

Comment: I'm ok with upgrading my OS, I'd even like it. But I don't know how to reference the new installed version from python (1) or how to upgrade the OS-installed version of six.

I'm trying to bypass using virtual environments for this if it is any way possible.

Comment: I'm telling you how to upgrade the OS version.

Comment: Yes, you can bypass it using virtualenv.